# How to Deal with Factually Wrong Answers

Tags: discussion, answers, comments, voting

Reading through some answers seam to be factually wrong. I am not sure if it is a standpoint in another school hence there is a dilemma on how to deal with them. People who as the question and would be readers may end up confused or misguided.

Answer (score 3):

I would put a comment in asking for clarification. Maybe it is a different school that has that interpretation. If no satisfactory answer came back then I would downvote. I personally would always leave a comment about why you have downvoted but that is just me.

Of course if it is abusive or inflammatory in any way then I would flag for moderator attention.

Answer (score 3):

Unless there is an obvious **factual** mistake (e.g. someone says s\he quotes Majjhima Nikaya while obviously quoting Milinda Panha) I would not rush with comments. We don't want to discourage new users by long flamewars in the comments. Certainly, if you asked for clarification *once* and the author responded, but you are still not satisfied, I would strongly recommend to restrain your horses. Instead, post your own answer with whatever facts you consider valid. If you absolutely *must* argue, please kindly proceed to chat, and there discuss your point to your heart's content.

Also, remember the following:

> ...
>   -- 'As for Kashyapa... You see, Asvajit' -- sighed Gotama, 'some people believe that the purpose of philosophical debate is to outargue the opponent and prove one's superior understanding.'
>   -- 'But this is so, Master Gotama, the one who wins the dispute, he must be the wiser, right?'
>   -- 'One who is really wise, Asvajit, debates not to win.'
>   -- 'What point is to argue then?!'-- As far as common sense Kaundinya had no equal.
>   -- 'It is quite pointful still. **The point is, for the two sides, through combining two different understandings of the same problem, to free themselves from mistaken fixations, each side from their own.'**
>   ...

Comment: Any argument in comments or chat does not take you any where. The problem remains unsolved as the person reading will not get the best / right information. We need to have something to achieve this.

Comment: I will gladly consider your constructive ideas on the topic :)

Comment: One possibility is to request a reference/citation. It's one thing to post one's personal opinion (that's allowed on this site, is it?). But it's another thing to misquote (misrepresent) someone else. A possibility would be to post a comment, "Are you sure: where does it (the literature of your school) say that? What does it say exactly? Could you please provide a reference and a quote?" At the very least, such a comment would be a signal to any future reader that that point is unreferenced and surprising, perhaps debatable or contentious.